# Decoding non-latin characters when parsing a site with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, encoding

Herewith I get a table from the site: http://www.bvbf.ru/food_paper.html

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.bvbf.ru/food_paper.html'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
table1 = soup.find('table', id='table1')
headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text
    headers.append(title)
mydata = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    row_data = j.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in row_data]
    length = len(mydata)
    mydata = mydata.append(pd.Series(row, index=mydata.columns[:len(row)]), ignore_index=True)
```

I get the dataframe, but get in it Ð´ÐµÐ»Ð¸Ð¹, Ð±ÑÐ. Same characters are in the html code of the page. Is there a way to convert them to the way how they appear on the site (Cyrillic letters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
```

to this:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
```

You should get something like this:

```bash
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+
|    | Наименование продукции          | Плотность (гр/м2)   | Формат (мм)                       | Единица измерения    |
|----+---------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------|
|  0 | Оберточная бумага марки «Д»     | 40-60               | 840                               | тн                   |
|  1 | 80                              | 840                 | тн                                | nan                  |
|  2 | 40-60                           | 1050                | тн                                | nan                  |
|  3 | 80-120                          | 1050                | тн                                | nan                  |
|  4 | Бумаг оберточная / влагостойкая | 80                  | 103, 107, 121, 125, 118, 120, 123 | тн                   |
+----+---------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: To expand on the answer: page.text is treated as a text stream and is converted to UTF-8. the requests package applies an encoding detector to detect the encoding of the response. In this case it detects ISO-8859-1 and applies an encoding conversion, resulting in a double encoded text, ie UTF-8 text treated as ISO-8859-1 and converted to UTF-8 again. Double encoded. page.content is treated as a binary stream and no encoding conversion is performed on it, so it comes through as UTF-8.